# NextJS API file import location

Tags: next.js, ejs

I'm using EJS to build email templates. The problem I'm having is I don't know what is the best location to keep these EJS files and any other file import for production (could be even a zip file in future).

Currently I'm keeping email templates under `src/emails` folder (next root is src).  I performed a test with the following and everything works fine :

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import path from 'path';
const ejs = require('ejs')

type Data = {
  name: string;
};

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const basePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/emails');

  ejs.renderFile(basePath + '/userVerification.ejs', { verifyURL: 'testurl' }, (err: {}, data: any) => {
    console.log(data);

    res.status(200).end('test');
  });
}
```

But I noticed NextJS is getting the file from src folder which won't be available on server. I thought maybe I can put them into src/public folder since it'll be exported but I couldn't make sure.

My question is where is the best location for keeping these files?

Comment: After adding your files to `public/emails` folder, why don't you try to build your project using `next build` and run using `next start`, and verify if it's working as expected?

Comment: Actually later I realized that I can create folder in root, separated from src and public and maintain those files in there. Apparently only public accessible folder is public, rest is only available access by server.

Answer (score 0):

After performing a few tests, I noticed that `api` can actually access to anything within project folder. Only `public` folder content can be accessed publicly by URL. That being said folder location for custom files can be anywhere.

```
.next
public
server_files *(all files can be imported by API)*
--ejs (templates email templates)
--pdf (generated invoice etc.)
--zip
src
--components
--pages
```